# Jquery Libraries - performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a question to discuss - page performance and speed when adding additional javascript libraries and css files for certain widgets, plugins etc.

For example: I wanted a simple datepicker and additional timepicker for my input fields.

What i had to integrate was JQuery UI library, timepicker script, +2 different css files.

I think thats alot of additional code. I dont have many experience with speed, so thats why I'm asking you guys, how much does all that additional stuff affect page speed and performance?

Is change noticeable?

Comment: Javascript operates at millions of ops/sec. Unless you include a really poor library/plugin or overloaded css with images, the difference will be in the decimals of milliseconds. Of course, loading time not included. jQuery and other popular libraries are usually already cached in the users' browsers so using a CDN-hosted one should take only a couple milliseconds to retrieve a 302 status from the CDN.

Comment: The biggest hit in performance will come from the extra server requests grabbing these files. If possible, at launch try to keep as few .js and .css files as possible.
For instance, I usually keep all my javascript in a file named scripts.js and all .js plugins in a file called plugins.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you integrate the code is going to matter a lot more than the fact that the code is there.  If you keep them all in separate files and include them in the head of your page then it is likely to slow your page down quite a bit (just from the round trips to fetch the code).

If you can, you should:
- Merge the css in with your existing site css (which should be in the head and cacheable)
- Put all of the script for the time picker and supporting libraries into a single js file
- Load the javascript asynchronously or rught at the end of your body so it doesn't block any of the page content from loading

You also need to be careful for how you attach the code to the elements on the DOM.  If you have a reasonably complicated DOM then something like $(".mycalendar").xxx can be incredibly expensive, particularly on older IE browsers.  If at all possible, use an ID for the elements and select using that, otherwise JQuery will end up walking the entire DOM (and yes, javascript execution itself is fast but anything that touches the DOM is not).